# Prove that translation invariance implies inverse invariance without using the uniqueness of the measure

Tags: alternative-proof, locally-compact-groups, haar-measure

From the last paragraph of the proof for Claim V.11.8, [1], we know that

**Lemma**. There is a unique regualr positive Borel measure $m$ on a compact group $G$ such that
$$m(g\Delta)=m(\Delta)=m(\Delta g)\forall g\in G \mbox{ and } \Delta\subset G.$$

> Exercise V.11.4, [1]. Let $G$ be a locally compact group. If $m$ is a regular Borel measure on $G$, show 
>   that any two of the following properties imply the third:
>
> 1. $m (\Delta g)= m(\Delta)$ for 
>      every Borel set $\Delta$ and every $g$ in $G$;
> 2. $m(g\Delta) = m(\Delta)$ for every Borel set $\Delta$
>      and every $g$ in $G$;
> 3. $m(\Delta) = m(\Delta^{-1})$ for every Borel set $\Delta$.

*My Proof*. 1 and 3 imply 2. For every Borel set $\Delta$
and every $g$ in $G$,
 \begin{align*}
m(g\Delta)=m(\Delta^{-1}g^{-1})=m(\Delta^{-1})=m(\Delta)
\end{align*}

1 and 2 imply 3. 
This holds for all compact subsets of $G$ by the above lemma.
This also holds for all open subset of $G$ because 
\begin{align*}
m(U)= & \sup\{m(K)|K\subset U \mbox{ is compact.}\}\\
= &\sup\{m(K^{-1})|K\subset U \mbox{ is compact.}\}\\
= &\sup\{m(K^{-1})|K^{-1}\subset U^{-1} \mbox{ is compact.}\}\\
=& \sup\{m(K)|K\subset U^{-1} \mbox{ is compact.}\}
\end{align*}
Since $m(V)=\inf\{m(U)|U\supset V \mbox{ is open.}\}$ for any Borel set $V$, we can prove the same holds for all Borel subset of $G$ similarily.

> **Question**. Can we prove "1 & 2 $\Rightarrow 3$" directly, without using the uniqueness of $m$ satisfying 1 & 2?

[1] *Conway, John B.*, A course in functional analysis., Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 96. New York etc.: Springer-Verlag. xvi, 399 p. DM 148.00 (1990). [ZBL0706.46003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0706.46003).

Comment: The uniqueness of the Haar measure is such a sweet and cherished property that it is simply wrong to reject it as a tool. Anyway, you can always use the [Riesz-Markov representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz-Markov-Kakutani_representation_theorem) as a substitute, but this approach is based on the uniqueness part of this theorem, so you still get to use some form of uniqueness.